# How do I use PHP locally with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am a desktop application / database programmer customizing an ERP application in a Windows environment.  I have also done documentation with HTML and javascript on our intranet.  I have not done any web programming.

I need to convert an Access 2003 application.  Instead of using .Net I think it would be wiser to use HTML to allow access from a tablet.  This app will display drawings based on certain lookup values (i.e. part number) stored in a SQL server database.  After some research it seems PHP is the best choice.  But the things I have found explain on a server supplying the pages and not running locally.  I see Apache and IIS mentioned but are these needed if the pages will be loaded on a single machine (or multiple machines but all pages will be present in a single directory structure).

When I search for running pages locally I get pages accessing a databse locally.  But the database will be on a server.

Can someone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for. You have one central server? And now you have the task of developing a front end? Or a bit more than a front end, something that implements business logic? And you're now considering your options for this ...let's call it rich client (without putting too fine a point on it)? Please elaborate on the setup, constraints and requirements.

Comment: I'm understanding that you want to serve out the finished result in HTML. When you say you want to run the process locally, how locally do you mean: On your own computer or on a small LAN? or???

Comment: I have a database server.  There will be no web server.  I want a stand alone app built with html.  I need data from a database.  From my research it seems to suggest php is the best choice.

Comment: In other words I want any machine on our network to be able to access the data in SQL server via a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the presented data to be web-accessible (or at least not public), but you do want the presentation to be through HTML-pages, I can come up with two ideas:

1. Use a scripting language to access MS SQL Server, extract the data, and present it as HTML. Since you like PHP, maybe [Perl with a suitable DB-access library might be a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983586/accessing-microsoft-sql-server-from-windows-in-perl).
2. PHP as you suggest, [some kind of web-server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-nweb/index.html), and a [rigorous lock-down configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/276963/make-apache-only-accessible-via-127-0-0-1-is-this-possible) so that the webserver is only accessible locally. Depending on the sensitivity of your data, this might be the worse option.

Comment: The only reason I chose PHP is that is what I saw mentioned in the majority of my searches.  I'm open to something else if it works better.  I don't understand what the purpose of a web server is.  I need an HTML page to read from a database.  Where does the web server fall into this?

Comment: The webserver would allow you to make fancier web-pages, but you can come pretty far with local HTML files. In that case I'd go with a scripting language (e.g. python, perl or ruby) with a database-access library.

Comment: It appears I made a poor choice deciding on using PHP.  I have not used python, perl or ruby.  Which one is best suited for my task?  Populating a combobox on a web page where the code will be static.  After a quick glance it seems I will have to build the entire page with one of those, which is fine.  Just don't know which direction would be best.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use PHP then if you put your application online you can use MySql for the database. You will not need to make any changes because any web server uses mysql with php. 
If you want to use PHP with SQL server then you will need on your server to install the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server . in the following link you will have the documentation:
[www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098][1]

Comment: The application will not be online.  It will be run locally.  Due to US government export restrictions it would be illegal to put this information online.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built-in webserver since 5.4.0: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

If you have PHP (>= 5.4) on your machine, you already have a webserver.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, installing PHP 5.4 on a machine will allow a HTML page to access a SQL Server database on a server.  Can you point me to an example of using PHP to access SQL Server data?

Comment: This will only allow you to serve .php files from a directory in a convenient way. I think DB-access is beyond. But SQL (MsSQL?) access is possible with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php. You'd need a webserver though. Depends on your OS on what to install.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Internet Information Server on your Windows system (using "Turn Windows Features on or off in the control panel) and install PHP: http://php.iis.net/

Alternatively Apache xampp installs the Apache webserver, MySQL (when wanted) and PHP on your system: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html. To connect to Sql Server you have to remove the semicolon `;` before the `extension=php_mssql.dll` line in the `php.ini`.

Comment: I do not want MySQL.  The data lives in SQL Server.

Comment: Well, with Xampp you disable MySQL, with IIS you do not install it

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you want to have the database on the tablet. That is possible, simply by installing the web and database server locally. Restrictions might apply depending on your tablet (OS) manufacturer though.
You could also have a "regular" web server / database server setup, and use the localstorage of your tablet's browser to have the result pages available in offline mode, and sync your data when possible, using php and maybe ajax scripts.

Comment: The database resides on a server.  I want the capability to access the information on a tablet.  Initially it will be run from a desktop PC.

Comment: If you have network access from the tablet, a normal web application should satisfy your needs.
If you do not have or do not always have network access, take a look at `localstorage`.

Comment: To clarify things a bit: A web server would create the html pages from the data of your database server. this can be requested through any browser. The web server doing the heavy lifting (retrieving the data, drawing your images, creating the html output) then provides the resulting html pages and images to your client(s). PHP would run on the web server to achieve this. The clients do nothing but request the resulting pages.

Comment: I don't understand why a web server would "create the html page."  The html page is static with, for example, a drop down with data from the database.  When you say "creating the page" are you referring to populating a dropdown?  Perhaps I am thinking too much like a desktop developer, but I fail to see the benefit of a server creating a static page when the only thing that needs to be dynamic is the data.

Comment: Since you are trying to get data from a database, you want this data to be formatted in some way. Say, a table. Or an image, or something. Creating the HTML is what a web server is for (broadly speaking) so, if you request database record A, the html is created such as to present you with a nicely formatted page to show the data. for record B you get different html (since the data is different, maybe even the layout, because for record B you might need a different "look" in the page.

Comment: The reason to use a web server, as compared to a file server, for accessing your html pages is: The web server will create the HTML files for you, on the fly, being able to incorporate the latest version of the data from your DB. You could also create static HTML pages by hand, but that would mean you had to create every single possible page and store in#t in the file system. And change them manually should the data in the DB change.

Comment: But this situation is different.  There is only 1 page, ever.  The reason for using HTML is portability, not the need for anything dynamic.  And I do not need the data formatted at all.  Think combobox.  It presents a list of choices.  That is what I need.  The choices are dynamic, not the page.  The only thing different will be the path returned based on user selection.  The path will be used for further processing.  Again, nothing dynamic.